# How to display empty textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm currently working in JSP and I want to have two large empty boxes side by side, however the only way for the boxes to display in full is if they have characters in them.(ie I currently have two large boxes side by side with an 'a' in each.)

Also, I'd like my header to automatically display them equidistant from either side of the screen as opposed to having to manually add padding:

```
    <%@ page %>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" />
<head>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css"></link>

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css"></link>

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<style>
#header {
    background-color:white;
    color:black;
    text-align:center;
    padding:5px;
}

</style>
<style> #Container2 div { float: left; width: 800px; height: 575px; border: 3px solid black; } </style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="header">
<h1>1</h1>
</div>
<p>Please Choose an Object</p>
<select>
    <option value="0" selected="selected">Select...</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option> 
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
</select>
<p></p>
<div id = "container" style = "width:100%">
    <div id ="left" style = "float:left; width: 25%;">
    <p>Please Choose an HTTP Request</p>
<select>
    <option value="0" selected="selected">Select...</option>
    <option value="GET">GET</option>
    <option value="POST">POST</option> 
    <option value="PUT">PUT</option>
    <option value="DELETE">DELETE</option>
</select>
    </div>
    <div id = "middle" style = "float:left; width: 50%;">
    <p>Please Choose an ID</p>
<select>

</select>
    </div>
    <div id = "right" style = "float:left; width: 25%;">
    <p>Please Choose a Type</p>
<select>
    <option value="0" selected="selected">Select...</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option> 
    <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
    </div>
</div>

<p align="right">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span> Submit</button>
 </p>
 <p></p>
 <div id="Container2"> <div>a</div> <div>a</div> </div> 

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: the way SO works is you show what you have implemented thus far and then you can ask questions and get answers/recommendations. so have a go yourself and then post your work. thanks

Comment: Sorry, I tried to do that for the first part of the question but because its html it just displayed the two 'a's in the body of the question.  <div id="Container2"> <div>a</div> <div>a</div> </div>

Comment: that's ok, your new, you should add your code to the original post however by clicking 'edit', rather than posting code within the comments section

Comment: can you post the full html document rather than just this snippet

Comment: first of all you can put all your styling within one style tag, you don't need to open style tags every time you want to style an individual div/element. secondly, your Container2 does not have any textarea tags or input tags within each div?

Comment: I know you are new here, but you really need to research using HTML elements by reading the documentation or watching a tutorial series, not a criticism just a suggestion

Comment: Alright, will do, thank you.

Comment: also, let me know if this solves your issue so we can close the question off as answered

Comment: glad to hear that, if my above advice solved the issue then let me know so I can provide it as an answer and you can mark it as correct. or if you solved it yourself then describe how you fixed it with your own answer. either way it closes the question off as answered and others can use this to find a solution to a similar issue

Comment: Your answer was correct.

Comment: ok, just posted it as an answer, please tick it as correct for the aforementioned reason, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, you can put all your styling within one `style` tag, you don't need to open style tags every time you want to style an individual div/element.

Secondly, your *Container2* does not have any `textarea` tags or `input` tags within each `div`. So having just a empty div without any text or textarea/input element then there will be nothing displayed as a **div** merely acts as a **container** where you can group elements into sections and then apply styling to that div/section.